# While calculating x^n using recursion a test case fails with following error?

Tags: c++, recursion, math

Quesion: [Question Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/)

The question is to calculate the power of x to n where n can be in
range :-2^31 <= n <= 2^(31-1)

But for certain test case code seems to give stack overflow error:

Test Case for which the code fails:

x = 0.00001

n = 2147483647

## Error:
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffe5053aff8 (pc 0x000000343a6a bp 0x7ffe5053b010 sp 0x7ffe5053b000 T0)
==31==ABORTING

How can I handle the stack overflow in this ?

MYCODE:

```
double myPow(double x, long long n) {
         double res;
         // long long nn=abs(n);
        // BC
        if(n==0)
            return 1;
        if(x==0) 
            return 0;
        
             res=myPow(x,abs(n)-1);
             return n<0?1/(x*res):x*res;
}
```

Here I changed the data type of the n which was initially int to counter the overflow issue.
If there is any other way too counter that do tell?

Also I had written the optimised version of Code which any more improvements that can be made is appreciated..

Optimised Code:

```
 double myPow(double x, int n) {
         double res;
         long long nn=abs(n);
        // BC
        if(n==0)
            return 1;
        if(x==0) 
            return 0;
        
        if(nn%2==0){
            res=myPow(x,nn/2);
            res=res*res;
            return n<0?1/res:res;
        }
        else {
             res=myPow(x,nn-1);
             return n<0?1/(x*res):x*res;
        }
}
```

Comment: @pjs modified is it understandable..

Comment: Please tag the language involved. Also how meany people died from the deadly signal?

Comment: On modern systems any recursive function that calls itself more than 40-50 times results in a stack overflow. Every recursive call stores the return address in the stack and it eventually fills up.

Comment: Oh!!  but how then i can resolve the error in the first piece of code any idea @JohnAlexiou

Comment: Changing to exponentiating by squaring should work. Then the depth is at most 31, instead of 2 billion.

Comment: There's no computer system I know of that's going to pass that test.  (1.0e-5)^2147483647 = 10^-1.073741e10.  No IEEE floating point representation can handle that.  Your problem isn't recursion; it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

A possible improvement would be to eliminate some local variables in the recursive function, to save some stack space:

```
double power(double x, int n) {
    if( x==0 ) return 0;
    if( n==0 ) return 1;
    if( n%2 == 0 ) return power(x*x, n/2);
    return x*power(x*x, n/2);
}

double myPow(double x, int n) {
    double p = power(x, abs(n));
    return n<0 ? 1/p : p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the  optimised code  ,But can you explain how this code shall handle the test case mentioned.

Comment: @PrakharGarg In each recursive call, the least significant digit of the binary representation of *n* is removed (because it is divided by 2). Thus, the number of recursive calls is equal to the number of bits in the binary representation of *n* (i.e., at most 31 bits) and, therefore, the stack size will be very small (avoiding stack overflow error).